# Print Json string using PHP

Tags: php, json

### Json String

### I need to iterate the String and print whole data.

I m getting illegal offset while printing it.##

```
$string = '{  
       "ConditionArray":[  
          {  
             "condition_image":"\/storage\/emulated\/0\/androidlav\/470-twitter.jpg (image\/jpg)",
             "condition_name":"Maleria",
             "profile_id":"49"
          },
          {  
             "condition_image":"\/storage\/emulated\/0\/androidlav\/470-twitter.jpg (image\/jpg)",
             "condition_name":"Maleria",
             "profile_id":"49"
          }
       ],

    "AllergiesArray":[  
          {  
             "condition_image":"\/storage\/emulated\/0\/androidlav\/470-twitter.jpg (image\/jpg)",
             "condition_name":"exapample",
             "profile_id":"50"
          },

       ]
    }';
```

Comment: show your error code !

Comment: use json_decode function to decode and convert it into php array  then iterate

Comment: using code: $json = json_encode($string, true); print $json['ConditionArray']['condition_image'];

Comment: Warning: Illegal string offset 'ConditionArray' in D:\xampp\htdocs\noorisys\aawlascope\ws\test.php on line 43

Comment: while using json_decode it is showing blank screen.

Comment: you have used wrong function use json_decode instead of json_encode

Comment: @aman - same blank screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the error in you json string it's not properly encoded

**Invaild json object**

```
$string = '{
    "ConditionArray": [{
        "condition_image": "\/storage\/emulated\/0\/androidlav\/470-twitter.jpg (image\/jpg)",
        "condition_name": "Maleria",
        "profile_id": "49"
    }, {
        "condition_image": "\/storage\/emulated\/0\/androidlav\/470-twitter.jpg (image\/jpg)",
        "condition_name": "Maleria",
        "profile_id": "49"
    }],

    "AllergiesArray": [{
        "condition_image": "\/storage\/emulated\/0\/androidlav\/470-twitter.jpg (image\/jpg)",
        "condition_name": "exapample",
        "profile_id": "50"
    }, // => this line contain the error it has extra comma 
  ]
}';
```

use http://jsonlint.com/ to validate the json

**Valid json object**

```
$string = '{
    "ConditionArray": [{
        "condition_image": "\/storage\/emulated\/0\/androidlav\/470-twitter.jpg (image\/jpg)",
        "condition_name": "Maleria",
        "profile_id": "49"
    }, {
        "condition_image": "\/storage\/emulated\/0\/androidlav\/470-twitter.jpg (image\/jpg)",
        "condition_name": "Maleria",
        "profile_id": "49"
    }],

    "AllergiesArray": [{
        "condition_image": "\/storage\/emulated\/0\/androidlav\/470-twitter.jpg (image\/jpg)",
        "condition_name": "exapample",
        "profile_id": "50"
    }
  ]
}';

var_dump(json_decode($string));
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have extra comma in last line of AllergiesArray array

```
 "AllergiesArray":[  
          {  
             "condition_image":"\/storage\/emulated\/0\/androidlav\/470-twitter.jpg (image\/jpg)",
             "condition_name":"exapample",
             "profile_id":"50"
          }, <--- remove this comma
    ]

$json =  (array)json_decode($string);  //convert array
print $json['ConditionArray'][0]->condition_image;
```